# Where is/should be created wpa_supplicant.conf on Debian

Tags: debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I want to set my regulatory domain on debian stable but i can't seem to find `wpa_supplicant.conf` wich resided under `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` on fedora.
Does anyone know where to find it on debian?

Just to clarify i use NetworkManager to manage my networks.

Comment: A Google for "wpa supplicant debian" reveals [The Debian WiFi Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant), which states to add items to `/etc/network/interfaces` Be Studious because some will downvote this since the Wiki was the 1st result.  Welcome to U&L.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find another way of setting the regulatory domain in debian which is setting the `REGDOMAIN` variable in `/etc/default/crda`